# How to handle list of edit text in single screen using By.classname in appium?

Tags: java, android-edittext, appium

I have list of edittext in single screen and I used the following code snippet for locating and sending the values to edittext.

```
List edit_text = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));
edit_text.get(0).sendKeys("xxxx");
edit_text.get(1).sendKeys("1234");
```

The above is working fine .
I need to change the above code by using By.classname.

**File1.java**

```
List edit_text = (List) By.className("android.widget.EditText");  
public void driver_mobile(){   
    driver.findElementsByClassName(edit_text);
}
```

**File2.java:**

Need to call the `driver_mobile()` method in this file for different index of `edit_text`.

```
File1 obj= new File1(driver)
obj.driver_mobile().edit_text(0).sendKeys("xxxx");
obj.driver_mobile().edit_text(1).sendKeys("1234");
```

The error is showing in the file2 snippet and in file 1 `driver.findElementsByClassName(edit_text);` line. I dont know how to use this properly. Can anyone say how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use the POM stratergy

> File1.java

AndroidDriver driver;

//  Here edit according to your driver type

public File1(AndroidDriver dr) {

driver=dr;

}

public List driver_mobile(){

return (List) driver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.EditText");

}

> File2.java

File1 obj= new File1(driver);

obj.driver_mobile().get(0).sendKeys("xxxx");

obj.driver_mobile().get(1).sendKeys("1234");